# Retrofit + RealmList + Gson stuck in a loop until out of memory

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, realm

I'm trying to user Retrofit + Realm + Gson, but when the RealmList is used the app get stuck.

If I remove the RealmList objects everything work's fine, but I need the object list.

Logcat:

```
(32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 278516(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 23MB/31MB, paused 2.533ms total 1.049s
(32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 137132(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 4.211ms total 188.951ms
(32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 271335(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 3.998ms total 236.868ms
(32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 143812(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 6.470ms total 201.800ms
(32099): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 159223(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 23MB/39MB, paused 5.524ms total 215.809ms
(32099): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 278158(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 24MB/32MB, paused 1.922ms total 201.617ms
```

Json:

```
[
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Subcategory 1",
  "color": "FF0000",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Tab 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Tab 2"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "title": "Subcategory 2",
  "color": "DD0000",
  "tabs": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Tab 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Tab 2"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

Subcategory class:

```
public class Subcategory extends RealmObject {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("title")
private String title;
@SerializedName("color")
private String color;

@SerializedName("tabs")
private RealmList<Tab> tabs;

... sets & gets ...

}
```

Tab class:

```
public class Tab extends RealmObject {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

... sets & gets ...
}
```

RestClient use:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

services = retrofit.create(Services.class);

services.getSubcategories().enqueue(new Callback<RealmList<Subcategory>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<RealmList<Subcategory>> response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Size: " + response.body().size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Libs:

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
```

Comment: i have same issue can u help me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to configure an `ExclusionStrategy` for GSON as described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

Update: From Realm 0.89 it should no longer be necessary to define the exclusion strategy, the below should be enough:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem.

Comment: Thank you Sir, it is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: i have already updated Realm 0.89.1   but stiill having problem 
can u have any other solution??
when i remove realm line its work good :(

Comment: Upgraded to realm 1.1.0 and ran into the same problem with retrofit and gson.

Comment: Same on my side, running into this problem with latest realm version

Comment: This problem still persists even with Realm 2.0.1. Can this question answer be unmarked, or should I create a new question?

Comment: Make sure you put `transient` for those fields that you don't want to be parsed. I got a `View` field in my class that causes the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and the accepted answer didn't work for me despite of having realm version above 0.87. I am posting this in case anyone else faces this issue and accepted answer doesn't work.

I got it working by converting `RealmList<MyModel>` to `List<MyModel>` using `ream.copyFromRealm` function which creates in-memory copy of realm objects.

Something like this should work:

```
RealmList<MyModel> myModelRealmObjects = realmDBManager.getModelObjects();
List<MyModel> myModelObjects = realm.copyFromRealm(myModelRealmObjects);
```

And then pass `myModelObjects` to retrofit.

Comment: You, sir, are a mother ducking godsend. I have been trying to figure this issue out for **hours**. I think it has something to do with GSON parsing and the auto-update core functionality of Realm. After spam-loading a list of 6 small objects, I eventually threw an exception in GSON for having a stack level too deep. In any case, creating an in-memory copy definitely solves the issue!