# Using retrofit with realm is failing to get the json with objects inside

Tags: android, retrofit, realm, retrofit2

I 'm having problems when trying to use the retrofit with realm when I need to pick up an object that has other inner object.

The problem is the `.enqueue` method of retrofit never get a callback and it Looks like the parse is taking forever.

I got this in the logs

[image]

The code work when the model classes bellow has no other model within (Album and Artist).

The simple Json im parsing. It is an album with an artist inside.

```
{
    id: "2",
    name: "CoverGirl",
    image: "http://res.cloudinary.com/thefader/image/upload/s--Ky_sXRw2--/w_760,c_limit,q_jpegmini,f_auto/mila_j_cover_q96o4t.jpg",
    bigger: false,
    artist: {
        id: 2,
        name: "Mila J",
        image: "http://www.billboard.com/files/styles/article_main_image/public/media/mila-j-pose-2015-billboard-650.jpg"
    }
}
```

Album class

```
public class Album {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Artist artist;

    ...getter and setter for all attributes
}
```

Artist class

```
public class Artist extends RealmObject{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    ...getter and setter for all attributes
}
```

And i'm calling it using

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("my_url_is_here")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    GitHubService service = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
    //The problem is here. the enqueue method stops here, and in the log cat show the messages that is in the image I publish
    service.getAlbum().enqueue(new Callback<Album>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Album> call, Response<Album> response) {
            System.out.println();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Album> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    });
```

I think the problem is because my models extends `RealmObject` an retrofit can't parse it for some reason.

I just want a explanation or maybe a solution for this. Any answers will be very helpful.

Comment: You need to configure your GSON instance as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735639/retrofit-realmlist-gson-stuck-in-a-loop-until-out-of-memory/34736978#34736978

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Thank you, it was exactly what I was looking for.