# gson.toJson() gives memory issues with Realm

Tags: android, gson

In android application I am facing memory issue while performing gson.toJson(). I am doing below steps:

1. Retrieving the User details from Realm Database to User Class
2. Then updating the User class values like Name, Phone Number
3. Converting it to String representation using gson.toJson()

This time it give me memory error. User Class also has relation with ImageDetails and LocationDetails entity class.

**Error: "Background sticky concurrent mark sweep"**

Comment: Can you kindly post your class..

Comment: probably this thread will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735639/retrofit-realmlist-gson-stuck-in-a-loop-until-out-of-memory

Comment: @Debu I already tried the solution given the link you provided but no luck. Do you need the Entity class code ?

Comment: Yaaa kindly provide the class

Comment: `public class UserDetails extends RealmObject implements Serializable {


    private String dob;

    private String emailAddress;

    private String gender;

    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private VenueDetails prefferedLocation;

    private ImageDetails profilePic;

    private String loginUserName;

    private String loginUserPassword;
}`

Comment: It also has getter and setter but due to comment length limit only posting the variables defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the Problem

1. Add the following line in the build.gradle(project)-

   classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
2. Add the following line in the build.gradle(app)-

   apply plugin: 'realm-android'

The above 2 lines will include the latest version of Realm into your project.

3. Use the code below to convert Json obj to string -

   ```
                        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                       .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                           @Override
                           public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                               return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                           }

                           @Override
                           public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                               return false;
                           }
                       })
                       .registerTypeAdapter(Class.forName("com.wandertrails.realm.UserDetails"), new UserDetailsSerilizer())
                       .create();
                       Log.e("Json Value",gson.toJson(new UserDetails()));
   ```

Change **com.wandertrails.realm.UserDetails** to your class name

4. Create a JsonSerializer class to serialize the class manually -

   ```
   public class UserDetailsSerilizer implements JsonSerializer<UserDetails> {
   @Override
   public JsonElement serialize(UserDetails src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
       final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
       jsonObject.addProperty("dob",src.getDob());
       jsonObject.addProperty("emailAddress",src.getEmailAddress());
       jsonObject.addProperty("gender",src.getGender());
       jsonObject.addProperty("id",src.getId());
       return jsonObject;
   }}
   ```

Comment: In your suggestion you are creating JsonObject. Instead of that Why I can't directly create the String representation of the Object which I updated via Realm. Is this is limitation of Realm ?

Comment: Realm only allows getter and setter to be written in the class that extends RealmObject, kindly accept the answer if it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is having a *RawUser* class that doesn't extend RealmObject and use *Gson.toJson* on this new class.
You can add a *getRawUser* method in your Realm User class and then just have to write

```
gson.toJson(user.getRawUser());
```

to get your serialized object